# filter list based on string pattern of hyphen separated values

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, list

I have a list of strings with varying formats.  Some of them start with a hyphen separated date time followed by a string that's a mixture of 16 numbers of letters.  I would like to filter for only the strings that match this format.  I've provided input and out put examples below.  I'm not a regex expert, could someone please suggest a slick way to do this with python?

Input:

```
example_list=['2022-05-05-16-59-25-5840ZQ37F231D95W',
'wereD/22fdas/',
'mnkljlj/124kljf/oaahreljah',
'2022-09-11-16-59-25-5840XY37F231D95Z']
```

output:

```
['2022-05-05-16-59-25-5840ZQ37F231D95W',
'2022-09-11-16-59-25-5840XY37F231D95Z']
```

update:

using the suggestion below with re.match and list comprehension worked fine, thanks!

```
import re

[x for x in example_list if re.match("^\d{4}(-\d\d){5}-[A-Z\d]{16}$",x)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^\d{4}(-\d\d){5}-[A-Z\d]{16}$
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/sCJWMbIJr9ifbJ).

Regex breakdown:

- `^` start of input
- `\d{4}` 4 digits
- `(-\d\d){5}` 5 lots of a dash then 2 digits
- `[A-Z\d]{16}` 16 of a caps letter or a digit
- `$` end of input